# Is this past participle a modifier?

Tags: past-participles

> . . . we reject an analysis that has gerund and present participle as
>   different forms **syncretised** throughout the class of verbs. We have
>   therefore just one inflectional form of the verb marked by the -ing
>   suffix; we label it with the compound term ‘gerund-participle’ for the
>   verb-form.
>  (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

is ‘sycretised’ a modifier or a verb? What does the first clause mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.**

> is ‘syncretised’ a modifier or a verb?

Yes. That's what a *participle* is. :)

More seriously, I think most grammarians today would regard *syncretised throughout the class of verbs* as a "reduced relative clause":

> different forms **which have been** syncretised throughout the class of verbs.

**II.**

> What does the first clause mean?
>
> . . . we reject an analysis that has gerund and present participle as different forms . . .

*Has* is an awkward choice of words; *understands* or *regards* or *represents* might be clearer. Profs. Huddleston and Pullum reject the (traditional) understanding that the gerund and the present participle are two different things which by historical accident are written the same way. They claim it is just *one* thing, and they give it a new name which joins the two old names with a hyphen.

Me, I think the principle is correct and the name is awkward.